# Powershell auto complete settings.

Tags: powershell

I was wondering if there was anyway to change the way the current powershell autocomplete works. I have been using bash and had changed them to offer a few features that I'd like in my powershell experience.

Currently powershell as I'm writing a command with a folder it will tab autocomplete and also cycle through my folders. This works how I like but one feature that I miss is using partial matching of a command and hitting the up key and it would find that command that matches the rest of what I do.

So Id write 'echo test' 
Then id write other commands and try 'ec' and tap up and 'echo test' would complete and not the last command I typed

Just wondering if there is anyway anyway to get this back?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### One feature that I miss is using partial matching of a command and hitting <kbd>up</kbd>

You can use [`PSReadLine`](https://github.com/lzybkr/PSReadLine) (A bash inspired readline implementation for PowerShell) for this:

> PSReadLine
>
> This module replaces the command line editing experience in
>   PowerShell.exe for versions 3 and up. It provides:
>
> - Syntax coloring
> - Simple syntax error notification
> - A good multi-line experience (both editing and history)
> - Customizable key bindings
> - Cmd and emacs modes (neither are fully implemented yet, but both are usable)
> - Many configuration options
> - Bash style completion (optional in Cmd mode, default in Emacs mode)
> - Bash/zsh style interactive history search (CTRL-R)
> - Emacs yank/kill ring
> - PowerShell token based "word" movement and kill
> - Undo/redo
> - Automatic saving of history, including sharing history across live sessions
>     "Menu" completion (somewhat like Intellisense, select completion with arrows) via Ctrl+Space
>
> ...
>
> To set your own custom keybindings, use the cmdlet
>   Set-PSReadlineKeyHandler. For example, for a better history
>   experience, try:
>
> ```
> Set-PSReadlineKeyHandler -Key UpArrow -Function HistorySearchBackward
> Set-PSReadlineKeyHandler -Key DownArrow -Function HistorySearchForward
> ```
>
> With these bindings, up arrow/down arrow will work like PowerShell/cmd
>   if the current command line is blank. If you've entered some text
>   though, it will search the history for commands that start with the
>   currently entered text.

Source [PSReadLine](https://github.com/lzybkr/PSReadLine)

Comment: @James As per the source link put the bindings in `C:\Users\[User]\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1`. See the [Readme](https://github.com/lzybkr/PSReadLine/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: Worked great! And works in my vs code shell as well with no problems. And yeah I figured out the profile thing right after I asked it. Similar to .bashrc

Answer (score 0):

With Powershell Core we can set the PredictionSource property for PSReadLine as **History** to get auto suggestion.

Refer to the YouTube video for more details
https://youtu.be/I0iIZe0dUNw