# Use zsh-autosuggestions in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

[zsh-autosuggestions](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions) suggests commands as you type based on history and completions:

[image]

Is it possible to make zsh-autosuggestions work in PowerShell?

Is there an equivalent module which provides the same functionality?

Note that this is not a request on how to auto-complete like shown in [this other question](https://superuser.com/questions/1199882/powershell-auto-complete-settings). This is about showing the suggestion before you type it, in gray, in the same line you are typing, without having to press TAB to see the options. It's about emulating the beavior of zsh-autosuggestions like shown in the animated GIF.

Comment: I answered this some time ago :)

Comment: It's a product request, if it is not a duplicate, right now. It can be edited to make the product request less explicit, and improving it.